# How to change the styles of a Pie Chart in Superset

Tags: html, css, apache-superset

How to change the color and font size in a pie chart with CSS?

I tried:

```
#chart-id-142 .dashboard {
    font:44px/41px "Microsoft YaHei";font-size:44px;line-height:41px;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the pie chart you are referring to has the id "chart-id-142" and the inline style is "dashboard" this should work:

```
#chart-id-142.dashboard {
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 80%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: tks, but not work

Comment: Can you provide the code in the element with the id "chart-id-142"?  Just the first line between the "<" and ">" should do.